# Group labels in matplotlib barchart using Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

```
group   subgroup    obs_1    obs_2
GroupA  Elem1       4        0
        Elem2       34       2
        Elem3       0        10
GroupB  Elem4       5        21
```

and so on. As noted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib) this is actually doable in matplotlib, but I'd rather (if possible) use the fact that I already know the hierarchy (thanks to the MultiIndex). Currently what's happening is that the index is shown as a tuple.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have just two levels in the `MultiIndex`, I believe the following will be easier:

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
DF.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.grid(True, 'both')
minor_XT = ax.get_xaxis().get_majorticklocs()
DF['XT_V'] = minor_XT
major_XT = DF.groupby(by=DF.index.get_level_values(0)).first()['XT_V'].tolist()
DF.__delitem__('XT_V')
ax.set_xticks(minor_XT, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(DF.index.get_level_values(1), minor=True)
ax.tick_params(which='major', pad=15)
_ = plt.xticks(major_XT, (DF.index.get_level_values(0)).unique(), rotation=0)
```

[image]

And a bit of involving, but more general solution (doesn't matter how many levels you have):

```
def cvt_MIdx_tcklab(df):
    Midx_ar = np.array(df.index.tolist())
    Blank_ar = Midx_ar.copy()
    col_idx = np.arange(Midx_ar.shape[0])
    for i in range(Midx_ar.shape[1]):
        val,idx = np.unique(Midx_ar[:, i], return_index=True)
        Blank_ar[idx, i] = val
        idx=~np.in1d(col_idx, idx)
        Blank_ar[idx, i]=''
    return map('\n'.join, np.fliplr(Blank_ar))

plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
DF.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(cvt_MIdx_tcklab(DF), rotation=0)
```

Comment: the "more general" solution does not solve some problems: 1. minor tick labels may be duplicates, but they are also blanked. 2. it returns a map which causes a "TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()". Solved it by changing to "return list(map('\n'.join, np.fliplr(Blank_ar)))" 3. It is impossible to rotate labels with that solution. I will stick to the 2 level index solution, it is very nice. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think that there isn't a nice and standard way of plotting multiindex dataframes. I found the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502106/2783943) by @Stein to be aesthetically pleasant. I've adapted his example to your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib inline

group = ('Group_A', 'Group_B')
subgroup = ('elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4')
obs = ('obs_1', 'obs_2')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Group_A','elem1'),('Group_A','elem2'),('Group_A','elem3'),('Group_B','elem4')],
   names=['group', 'subgroup'])
values = np.array([[4,0],[43,2],[0,10],[5,21]])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df['obs_1'] = values[:,0]
df['obs_2'] = values[:,1]

def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]

def label_group_bar_table(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1

ax = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=False)
#Below 2 lines remove default labels
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_xlabel('')
label_group_bar_table(ax, df)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### How to create a grouped bar chart of a hierarchical dataset with 2 levels

You can create a subplot for each group and stick them together with `wspace=0`. The width of each subplot must be corrected according to the number of subgroups by using the [`width_ratios`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec) argument in the `gridspec_kw` dictionary so that all the columns have the same width.

Then there are limitless formatting choices to make. In the following example, I choose to draw horizontal grid lines in the background and a separation line between the groups by using the minor tick marks.

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2

# Create sample DataFrame with MultiIndex
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(group = ['GroupA', 'GroupA', 'GroupA', 'GroupB'],
                       subgroup = ['Elem1', 'Elem2', 'Elem3', 'Elem4'],
                       obs_1 = [4, 34, 0, 5],
                       obs_2 = [0, 2, 10, 21]))
df.set_index(['group', 'subgroup'], inplace=True)

# Create figure with a subplot for each group with a relative width that
# is proportional to the number of subgroups
groups = df.index.levels[0]
nplots = groups.size
plots_width_ratios = [df.xs(group).index.size for group in groups]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=nplots, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 4),
                         gridspec_kw = dict(width_ratios=plots_width_ratios, wspace=0))

# Loop through array of axes to create grouped bar chart for each group
alpha = 0.3 # used for grid lines, bottom spine and separation lines between groups
for group, ax in zip(groups, axes):
    # Create bar chart with horizontal grid lines and no spines except bottom one
    df.xs(group).plot.bar(ax=ax, legend=None, zorder=2)
    ax.grid(axis='y', zorder=1, color='black', alpha=alpha)
    for spine in ['top', 'left', 'right']:
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_alpha(alpha)
    
    # Set and place x labels for groups
    ax.set_xlabel(group)
    ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(x=0.5, y=-0.15)
    
    # Format major tick labels for subgroups
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha='center')
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', length=0, pad=10)
    
    # Set and format minor tick marks for separation lines between groups: note
    # that except for the first subplot, only the right tick mark is drawn to avoid
    # duplicate overlapping lines so that when an alpha different from 1 is chosen
    # (like in this example) all the lines look the same
    if ax.is_first_col():
        ax.set_xticks([*ax.get_xlim()], minor=True)
    else:
        ax.set_xticks([ax.get_xlim()[1]], minor=True)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=45, width=0.8, color=[0, 0, 0, alpha])

# Add legend using the labels and handles from the last subplot
fig.legend(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels(), frameon=False,
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.92, 0.5), loc="center left")

title = 'Grouped bar chart of a hierarchical dataset with 2 levels'
fig.suptitle(title, y=1.01, size=14);
```

[image: hierarchical_grouped_bar_chart]

---

Reference: [this answer by gyx-hh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824748/14148248)

Comment: You can find another example of this chart in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66121322/14148248).

Comment: Great answer, but it's disappointing that it requires so much code to do something that other plotting programs can do so easily. I wonder if this will be an option for pandas plotting in future.