# How to iterate over a pandas dataframe and compare certain columns based on a third column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I'm new to pandas and have difficulties in using its power in a convenient way.

I have a large dataframe with experimental data for two different tests which I'd like to compare. Ideally, the data is displayed in a plot.

```
## what I have:
import pandas as pd

ids = [
    'Bob','Bob',
    'John', 'John',
    'Mary', 'Mary',
    ]
var = [
    'a', 'b',
    'a', 'b',
    'a', 'b',
    ]
data = [
    10,11,
    15,14,
    10,15
    ]
dataset = zip(ids, var, data)
print dataset

columns = ['ids', 'var', 'data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataset, columns=columns)
print df

## what I want:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i,ii in enumerate(ids):
    if var[i] == 'a':
        ax1.plot(i/2, data[i], 'rs', label='var a')
    else:
        ax1.plot((i-1)/2, data[i], 'bo', label='var b')
majorLocator = MultipleLocator(1)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax1.grid()
ax1.margins(0.05)
ax1.set_xlabel('ids')
ax1.set_ylabel('data')
ax1.legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)
fig.show()
```

How can I do this properly without many many nested for loops? A plus would be if I could use the ids as the xlabels...

Thanks a lot in advance,
Daniel

Comment: i'm confused about what exactly you want the plot to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seaborn` does a lot of this for you, very flexibly:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.factorplot('ids', 'data', hue='var', kind='bar', data=df)
```

[image]

(it also restyles the plotting defaults, which can be changed or reset).

If you want to subset the data, pass the subset as the `data` argument:

```
sns.factorplot('ids', 'data', hue='var', kind='bar', 
               data=df[df.isin({'ids':['Bob','Mary']}).any(1)])
```

[image]

- that's with sns style turned off
- for any more complicated mask, you'd set up the mask separately; see the pandas docs

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need and want plotwise! Now, how can I combine this with the data filtering capabilities of pandas? For example, I only want to plot vars a and b, not c. Would I need to change the dataframe before plotting?

Comment: yes, seaborn and pandas work very well together -- see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html for  MANY MANY ways to subset `df`.

Comment: (and I put a filtered example into the answer)

Comment: Fantastic! I've just realized my Pandas module is outdated, too, thanks to your example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want end-goal wise, but if cphlewis's suggestion to go with seaborn isn't what you were looking for, you might try converting your DataFrame to a multiindex, instead, and plotting it out that way.

```
mi = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=[ids,var],columns=['data'])
f, a = plt.subplots()
mi.plot(kind='bar',ax=a)
```

[image: multiindex plot results]

It might also be helpful to reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22798832/2024873).

Comment: This definitely looks interesting. If not now, it could come in handy later, thanks!