# bar plot a multiheader dataframe in a desired format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data = {('Case1', 'A'): {'One': 0.96396415, 'Two': 0.832049574, 'Three': 0.636568627, 'Four': 0.765846157},
        ('Case1', 'B'): {'One': 0.257496625, 'Two': 0.984418254, 'Three': 0.018891398, 'Four': 0.440278509},
        ('Case1', 'C'): {'One': 0.512732941, 'Two': 0.622697929, 'Three': 0.731555346, 'Four': 0.031419349},
        ('Case2', 'A'): {'One': 0.736783294, 'Two': 0.460765675, 'Three': 0.078558864, 'Four': 0.566186283},
        ('Case2', 'B'): {'One': 0.921473211, 'Two': 0.274749932, 'Three': 0.312766018, 'Four': 0.159229808},
        ('Case2', 'C'): {'One': 0.146389032, 'Two': 0.893299471, 'Three': 0.536288712, 'Four': 0.775763286},
        ('Case3', 'A'): {'One': 0.351607026, 'Two': 0.041402396, 'Three': 0.924265706, 'Four': 0.639154727},
        ('Case3', 'B'): {'One': 0.966538215, 'Two': 0.658236148, 'Three': 0.473447279, 'Four': 0.545974617},
        ('Case3', 'C'): {'One': 0.036585457, 'Two': 0.279443317, 'Three': 0.407991168, 'Four': 0.101083315}}

pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

|  | Case1 | Case1 | Case1 | Case2 | Case2 | Case2 | Case3 | Case3 | Case3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
| One | 0,963964 | 0,257497 | 0,512733 | 0,736783 | 0,921473 | 0,146389 | 0,351607 | 0,966538 | 0,036585 |
| Two | 0,83205 | 0,984418 | 0,622698 | 0,460766 | 0,27475 | 0,893299 | 0,041402 | 0,658236 | 0,279443 |
| Three | 0,636569 | 0,018891 | 0,731555 | 0,078559 | 0,312766 | 0,536289 | 0,924266 | 0,473447 | 0,407991 |
| Four | 0,765846 | 0,440279 | 0,031419 | 0,566186 | 0,15923 | 0,775763 | 0,639155 | 0,545975 | 0,101083 |

There are 2 header rows.

In the end i need a plot like the following (which i created in excel).
Another solution would be a seperate plot for every Case, instead of all in one.

[image]

What i tried so far is:

```
df.T.melt(ignore_index=False)
```

to get the DataFrame in a format like i used in excel.
But from there i could not figure any solution to get the right plot. Maybe the transpose/melt is not even necessary.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to achieve the desired plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to reshape your dataframe first so the two levels of the x-axis be as a MultiIndex.

```
df = df.T.stack().unstack(level=1)
```

Then make the plot this way (highly inspired by @gyx-hh [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824748/16120011)) :

```
def plot_function(x, ax):
    ax = graph[x]
    ax.set_xlabel(x)
    return df.xs(x).plot.bar(ax=ax, legend=False, rot=0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(df.index.levels[0]),
                         sharey=True, figsize=(16, 4))

graph = dict(zip(df.index.levels[0], axes))
plots = list(map(lambda x: plot_function(x, graph[x]), graph))
ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", length=0)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

plt.legend()
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given your data, if it is in Excel, one would read it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('values.xlsx', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
```

To plot something very similar to what you would like:

```py
long_df = df.T.stack().reset_index()
long_df.columns = ['cases', 'subcases', 'observations', 'value']
transformed = long_df.pivot_table(
    index=['cases', 'observations'],
    columns='subcases',
    values='value',
    sort=False)
transformed.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: view of the created plot]

Explaining how it works:

1. long_df is a df normalized to a 'long' format using [stack function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html?highlight=stack#pandas.DataFrame.stack).
2. pivot data to get it in a correct orientation for simple plotting
3. plot in matplotlib using .plot method and bar option.