# Plotting Pandas Multiindex Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

How can I plot a Python Pandas multiindex dataframe as a bar chart with group labels? Do any of the plotting libraries directly support this? This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib?answertab=active#tab-top) shows a custom solution using matplotlib, but is there direct support for it?

As an example:

```
quarter  company
Q1       Blue       100
         Green      300
Q2       Blue       200
         Green      350
Q3       Blue       300
         Green      400
Q4       Blue       400
         Green      450
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

...can this dataframe be plotted with group labels [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5PJg.png)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
        ('Q1','Blue',100),
        ('Q1','Green',300),
        ('Q2','Blue',200),
        ('Q2','Green',350),
        ('Q3','Blue',300),
        ('Q3','Green',400),
        ('Q4','Blue',400),
        ('Q4','Green',450),
    ], 
    columns=['quarter', 'company', 'value']
)
data = data.set_index(['quarter', 'company']).value

data.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked bar chart from multiindex]

If you don't want to stack your bar chart:

```
data.unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: not-stacked bar chart]