# Difficulty grouping barchart using Python, Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am having difficulty getting plot.bar to group the bars together the way I have them grouped in the dataframe.  The dataframe returns the grouped data correctly, however, the bar graph is providing a separate bar for every line int he dataframe.  Ideally, everything in my code below should group 3-6 bars together for each department (Dept X should have bars grouped together for each type, then count of true/false as the Y axis).

Dataframe:

```
dname             Type  purchased
Dept X       0     False        141
                   True         270
             1     False       2020
                   True        2604
             2     False       2023
                   True        1047
```

Code:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 ##connection and query data removed

df = pd.merge(df_departments[["id", "dname"]], df_widgets[["department", "widgetid", "purchased","Type"]], how='inner', left_on='id', right_on='department')
df.set_index(['dname'], inplace=True)
dx=df.groupby(['dname', 'Type','purchased'])['widgetid'].size()
dx.plot.bar(x='dname', y='widgetid', rot=90)
```

[image: output from dataframe]

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without a more reproducible example, but try `unstack`ing the innermost level of the MultiIndex of `dx` before plotting:

```
dx.unstack().plot.bar(x='dname', y='widgetid', rot=90)
```

I expect this to work because when plotting a DataFrame, each column becomes a legend entry and each row becomes a category on the horizontal axis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this errors out "KeyError: 'dname'".  I'll look into the unstack functionality further.

Comment: @ByRequest, if you're still looking for a solution, I'd be curious to see the exact output (including whitespace) of `dx.head(10)`.

Comment: dname            Type  purchased
Department1      0     False        141
                       True         270
                 1     False       2020
                       True        2604
                 2     False       2023
                       True        1047
Name: widgetid, dtype: int64  --I'll add this to an image at the top as well since I do not believe my formatting will be retained.  Thanks!

Comment: Update - I played around a little bit more with Unstack() - it got me halfway there.  I now have three groups within one department.  So Departmentx, 0  gives me two bars for counts; Departmentx, 1 gives me two bars for counts - I just need the last piece to get all the bars together grouped by this particular department.  Perhaps this is a syntax issue?  As of right now what I am using is  df.groupby(['sname','Type','purchased'])['widgetid'].size().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=False)

Comment: I think the issue arises from having to plot a MultiIndex with three levels, whereas my `df.unstack().plot()` approach only works for two levels. This is where I hit my limit of knowledge about pandas/matplotlib plotting... Maybe this question and its linked question could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248741/plotting-pandas-multiindex-bar-chart