# dividing x axis one more on the bar graph

Tags: python, bar-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyPtd.png)

I am trying to create this on python, but I am not sure how to divide my axis one more.

any help is welcome.

I have no clue how to divide the x axis one more time. please help me thank you!!!!

Comment: Hey you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369681/how-to-plot-bar-graphs-with-same-x-coordinates-side-by-side-dodged

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting Pandas Multiindex Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248741/plotting-pandas-multiindex-bar-chart)