# Two level grouped plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is there any way to create a two level grouped bar chart (i.e. groups on the x-axis) using Python matplotlib and / or pandas.

An example of what I mean is shown [image: here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is on the [wishlist](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6321).
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242176/3805553) an example that is referred to in the post that does what you want, but with a couple of functions.

However, a quick solution would be to just plot two bar plots side-by-side and customising the graph a little bit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create multindex dataframe
arrays = [['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Veggies', 'Veggies', 'Veggies'],
          ['Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Carrots', 'Potatoes', 'Celery']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 50, size=(1, 6)), columns=index)

#plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(14 / 2.54, 10 / 2.54))  # width, height
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns.levels[0]):
    print(col)
    ax = axes[i]
    df[col].T.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', width=.8)

    ax.legend_.remove()
    ax.set_xlabel(col, weight='bold')
    ax.yaxis.grid(b=True, which='major', color='black', linestyle='--', alpha=.4)
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)

    for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
        tick.set_rotation(0)

#make the ticklines invisible
ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both', length=0)
plt.tight_layout()
# remove spacing in between
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)  # space between plots

plt.show()
```

[image]