# Visualizing pivot table with 3 variables via 2D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pivot table of three variables: `A`, `B`, and `C`. I want to plot this pivot table in the following 2D format using python.

```
 C  
30 |       x         x   x
20 |   x         x x   x  
10 | x   x   x x           x
     _______________________
  B  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
  A   1024    2048    4096
```

To the above plot, I want to add a plot of another pivot table with the same `A` and `B` values but with a different variable called `D`. Values of `D` must be connected by lines within the group of `B` values, i.e., `1`,`2`,`3`,and `4` for the same value of `A`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add group labels for bar charts in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Please provide better description of desired result. Image at best.