# I need to plot grouped data using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to plot countries departments and their sales. So i have country, departments and their sales numbers in diff columns. And i need to create bar plot, so it should look like country1 and its departments on x-axis and sales y-axis, then country2 and so-on.

I tried seaborn's catplot but its giving me a diff plot for each country, using plotly's bar its just plotting all the departments together. I need it to be grouped based on the countries.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: You have to share a little piece of your code if you want people to share with you a little bit of their knowledge.

Comment: I am sharing the example:
Main_Sector Country Count
0 Others USA  2923
1 Cleantech / Semiconductors USA  2297
2 Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising USA  1912
0 Others GBR 143
1 Cleantech / Semiconductors GBR 127
2 Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising GBR 98
0 Others IND 109
1 News, Search and Messaging IND 52
2 Entertainment IND 33

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`barplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) using `'Country'` as `x` and `'Department'` as `hue`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': np.repeat(['Albania', 'Botswana', 'Chili'], 4),
                   'Department': np.tile(['Department1', 'Department2', 'Department3', 'Department4'], 3),
                   'Sales': np.random.randint(10000, 100000, 12)})
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Country', y='Sales', hue='Department')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

An approach to cope with empty bars, is to create stacked bars:

```py
df.pivot(index='Country', columns='Department').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)
```

[image: stacked bars example]

Comment: This is pretty much what i was looking for. But, let's say there are some departments missing in some of the countries.Example: 
US finance 100
US sales 200
US HR 300
UK finance 250
UK transport 80
UK manufacturing 130

So, now its creating blanks in UK for sales and HR. Is there a way to tackle it

Comment: In that case the bar for that department will be empty.

Comment: Can i remove those blank bars?

Comment: I updated the answer with stacked bars, which don't have a problem with empty bars. Otherwise, [How to add group labels for bar charts in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib) might be worth looking at.  In general, I don't think there is a clear solution.

Comment: Thanks JohanC, The link you shared is very good. I am trying to get the solution from that. Much appreciated