# Bar plot with MultiIndex in X axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

Given the following dataframe

```py
data = {
    'Code': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'],
    'Month': [4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3],
    'Col A': [3, 0, 51, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 12],
    'Col B': [66, 5, 125, 5, 41, 52, 22, 14, 51, 122]
}

df = DataFrame(data)
d = df.groupby(['Month','Code']).sum()
```

[image: Dataframe]

How can I create a bar plot like this?:
[image: Desired plot]

Comment: Do you have tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502106/13075718 is exactly what I needed (I may do a few tweaks for aesthetics, but the logic is right)