# plot categorical plot using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

here is the my sample data set ,it is similar to my original data set

```
Country,state,sex,dist,population,LL,UL
IND,AP,F,EG,82,80,150
IND,AP,F,WG,150,80,150
IND,AP,F,VZA,95,80,150
IND,AP,F,BZA,116,80,150
IND,AP,M,EG,180,80,150
IND,AP,M,WG,158,80,150
IND,AP,M,VZA,77,80,150
IND,AP,M,BZA,114,80,150
IND,UP,F,A,86,80,150
IND,UP,F,B,179,80,150
IND,UP,M,C,83,80,150
IND,UP,M,D,146,80,150
```

i want to create the similar plot as below plot(which is created using excel) but i want to create it in python.
[image]
please help to create below plot using python, tried uisng matplotlib but could not replicate like below chart, mainly cannot pass column names to X-axis like below.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple solution to add hierarchical axis labels with matplotlib. Below I have created one solution adapted from the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502106/8252612). 'chart_data.csv' refers to the example data you provided.

[image: demo plot]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby

# add divider lines
def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='black')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

# Get counts for each label for this level
def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    #eg '[('AP', 8), ('UP', 4)]'
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]

# add divider lines and labels to plot
def add_xaxis_group_labels(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1

#define data
df = pd.read_csv('chart_data.csv')
df = df.set_index(['Country','state','sex','dist'])

# instantiate figure/axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df.plot(kind='line',ax=fig.gca())

# remove default labels
labels = ['' for _ in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel('')

#add new labels
add_xaxis_group_labels(ax, df)

#beautify
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=.1*df.index.nlevels)

#move legend outside
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))

plt.show()
```

If you want to keep things simple and you don't mind it being a bit messy, this is the easiest way to add all the labels:

[image: simple version]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('chart_data.csv')
df = df.set_index(['Country','state','sex','dist'])

df.plot(rot=90)
```

I would suggest however that as this is categorical data, the population data should be displayed as a bar chart, and the upper and lower limits as "threshold" lines. You can do this by changing kind='line' to kind='bar', and adding two threshold lines using plt.axhline(y=80, color='red') before plotting. You would also have to set df to only the population data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this using pandas data frame itself

```
df.plot()
```

(but x-axis label is diffrent)
[image]

Comment: simple df.plot() wont give X-Axis labels like one in the question

Comment: yes, Xlabel is default index values, i want to create the x axis label as one in my question, thats where i need help