# Combined xaxis and header of table with plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to do something quite similar to the picture with plotly on python. I tried to find a way with subplots and shared_axis but no way to find a correct way. Is it possible to share the x axis of a bar chart with the column titles of a table?

graph bar with shared xaxis
[image: graph bar with shared xaxis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- this can be simulated with two traces
- first trace is a standard bar chart, with **yaxis** **domain** constrained to 80% of the figure
- second trace is a bar showing values as text and a fixed height against a second **yaxis**.   **yaxis2** is constrained to 10% of the **domain**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"year": range(2011, 2022)}).assign(
    pct=lambda d: np.random.uniform(-0.08, 0.08, len(d))
)

px.bar(df, x="year", y="pct").add_traces(
    px.bar(df, x="year", y=np.full(len(df), 1), text="pct")
    .update_traces(
        yaxis="y2",
        marker={"line": {"color": "black", "width": 1.5}, "color": "#E5ECF6"},
        texttemplate="%{text:,.2%}",
    )
    .data
).update_layout(
    yaxis={"domain": [0.2, 1], "tickformat": ",.2%"},
    yaxis2={"domain": [0, 0.1], "visible": False},
    xaxis={"title": "", "dtick": 1},
)
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea, thank's you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502106/9022092) for matplotlib, I was able to do similar using Annotations in Plotly. You could improve by adding actual lines instead of `|` but this worked fine for my purposes. The nice part with this is it is interactive and the labels move left and right with the bars as you move or resize.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby


def test_table():
    data_table = pd.DataFrame({'Room':['Room A']*4 + ['Room B']*4,
                               'Shelf':(['Shelf 1']*3 + ['Shelf 2']*1)*2,
                               'Staple':['Milk','Water','Sugar','Honey','Wheat','Corn','Chicken','Cow'],
                               'Quantity':[10,20,5,6,4,7,2,1],
                               'Ordered':np.random.randint(0,10,8)
                               })
    return data_table

def add_line(fig, xpos, ypos):
    # print(xpos, ypos)
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=xpos,
        xref="x",
        xanchor="center",
        y=ypos,
        yref="paper",
        text="|",
        showarrow=False
    )

def add_text(fig, text, xpos, ypos, xanchor="center"):
    # print(text, xpos, ypos)
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=xpos,
        xref="x",
        xanchor=xanchor,
        y=ypos,
        yref="paper",
        text=text,
        showarrow=False
    )

def label_len(my_index, level):
    # returns list of tuple: [(level label, count)]
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]
    
def label_group_bar_table(fig, df, y_scale=0.1):
    for ii, level in enumerate(range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]):
        pos = 0
        ypos = -y_scale * (ii + 1)
        lv_name = df.index.names[level]
        add_text(fig, f"{lv_name}:  ", -0.5, ypos, xanchor="right")
        add_line(fig, -0.5, ypos)
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index, level):
            lbpos = (pos + 0.5 * (rpos - 1))
            lnpos = (pos + rpos - 0.5)
            # print(lbpos, lnpos, ypos, label)
            pos += rpos
            add_text(fig, label, lbpos, ypos)
            add_line(fig, lnpos, ypos)
    return fig

df = test_table().groupby(['Room','Shelf','Staple']).sum()
# display(df)
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(y=df["Quantity"], name="Quantity")
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(y=df["Ordered"], name="Ordered")
)
fig.update_layout(
    barmode="stack",
    xaxis_showticklabels=False,
    margin=dict(b=100)
    )
fig = label_group_bar_table(fig, df)
fig.show()
```

[image: multicategory plotly]