# How to set fixed color ranges with Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap with the Seaborn package, where I define my own color ranges. However, I cannot get the legend to show the values in a non-continous way. I would like the following color indication:

0-0.001: green

0.001-0.25: yellow

0.25-0.50: orange

0.50-0.75: red

0.75-1.00: dark red

But I get this:

[image]

I suspect that the first range disturbs the picture, because it is smaller. However, I would like the legens "boxes" or area to be the same sizes. Is it therefore possible to have something like this or similar:

[image]

The code that I currently use is the one below. Any hint or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
my_colors=['#02ab2e','gold','orange','red', 'darkred']


grid_kws = {"height_ratios": (.9, .025), "hspace": .1}
f, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(2, gridspec_kw=grid_kws)
ax = sns.heatmap(STEdata.iloc[:,3:13].reindex(ste_order_reg.sort_values().index, axis=0), 
                 yticklabels=2, ax=ax,
                 cmap = my_colors,
                 cbar_ax=cbar_ax, 
                 cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})
# sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(8, 18)})

colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, .75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0',']0-0.25]', ']0.25-0.50]',']0.50-0.75]', ']0.75-1.00]'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set uneven color ranges, a `BoundaryNorm` can be used.  The colorbar ticks   can be positioned at the center of each range. A `ListedColormap` creates a colormap from a list of colors.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

my_colors = ['#02ab2e', 'gold', 'orange', 'red', 'darkred']
my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_colors)
bounds = [0, 0.0001, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1]
my_norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=len(my_colors))

grid_kws = {"height_ratios": (.9, .025), "hspace": .1}
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8,18), gridspec_kw=grid_kws)
sns.heatmap(np.clip(np.random.rand(21, 12) - 0.1, 0, 1),
            yticklabels=2, 
            ax=ax,
            cmap=my_cmap,
            norm=my_norm,
            cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
            cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})

colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([(b0+b1)/2 for b0, b1 in zip(bounds[:-1], bounds[1:])])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', ']0-0.25]', ']0.25-0.50]', ']0.50-0.75]', ']0.75-1.00]'])

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with BoundaryNorm]

Instead of a colormap, a custom legend could be created. The same `BoundaryNorm` will be needed to assign the correct colors in the heatmap. `ax.text()` and `ax.hlines()` can be used to place text and lines for the grouping.  The [y-axis transform](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) uses the y-coordinates of the data and x coordinates as a fraction of the axes. `clip_on=False` allows drawing outside the main plot area.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

unavail_color = 'lightgray'
my_colors = ['#02ab2e', 'gold', 'orange', 'red', 'darkred']
my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_colors)
bounds = [0, 0.0001, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1]
my_norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=len(my_colors))

data = np.exp(np.random.rand(21, 12)) - 1
data[data > 1] = np.nan

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 18))
ax.set_facecolor(unavail_color)
sns.heatmap(data,
            yticklabels=2, ax=ax,
            cmap=my_cmap,
            norm=my_norm,
            cbar=False)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)

group_edges = np.array([0, 5, 6, 13, 14, 21])
group_labels = ['group A', '', 'group B', '', 'group C']
ax.hlines(group_edges, np.zeros(len(group_edges)), np.zeros(len(group_edges)) - 0.12,
          color='navy', lw=2, clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
for label, b0, b1 in zip(group_labels, group_edges[:-1], group_edges[1:]):
    ax.text(-0.12, (b0 + b1) / 2, label, color='navy', fontsize=20, ha='left', va='center',
            rotation=90, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())

handles = [Line2D([], [], lw=10, color=color, label=label)
           for color, label in zip(my_colors + [unavail_color],
                                   ['0', ']0-0.25]', ']0.25-0.50]', ']0.50-0.75]', ']0.75-1.00]', 'unavailable'])]
ax.legend(handles=handles, handlelength=0.5, ncol=len(my_colors) + 1,
          bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.02), loc='upper center', frameon=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with custom legend]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Do you by any chance know, if it is possible to add group labels for the y axis? Such as in your first figure:
0-4: 'group A', 6-12: 'group B', 14-20: 'group C'

Comment: Do you know if I can add groups based on a column in data set as well? I have the index column with the number and then a column with group names for each number? I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib/39502106#39502106, but I thought there would be a simpler way than this, just adding additional names.

Comment: All this kind of annotations needs manual adjustments, just like the linked post. There are too many things that would go wrong in an automatic solution.