# How to give specific color range for negative values while plotting sns heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, heatmap

I have a matrix , and I used sns for visualizing it, However , what I wish is :
if the value is anything less than 0, it should be blue,
if its in range of 0.0-0.99 it should be grey and
anything above 1, should be pink,

I tried as mentioned, but i am not sure how to tackle negative values,
I followed this :
[How to set fixed color ranges with Seaborn heatmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409131/how-to-set-fixed-color-ranges-with-seaborn-heatmap)

and the code that I generally used is:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (16,16))
sns.heatmap(p, annot=True, square=True)
```

[image]

Can anyone please suggest, how can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this: `uniform_data = np.array([np.random.uniform(-2, 2) for i in range(120)]);
uniform_data = uniform_data.reshape(10, 12);
my_colors = ['blue', 'gray', 'pink'];
my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_colors);
bounds = [-2, 0.0, 0.99, 2];
my_norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=len(my_colors));
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, annot=True, square=True, cmap=my_cmap, norm=my_norm)`

Comment: Why are negative numbers harder? You can use the `min` and `max` values of your matrix as extra boundaries