# ValueError: x must be a label or position when I try to Plot 2 columns in x axis grouped in area stacked chart using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pyspark

I have set of data with 3 columns Label, Year and Total. My total count is based on the group of label and year.

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+
|               Label|   Year|  Total|
+--------------------+-------+-------+
|                 FTP|02/2018| 193360|
|              BBBB  |01/1970|     14|
|              BBBB  |02/2018|4567511|
|                SSSS|02/2018| 187589|
|                Dddd|02/2018|  41508|
```

I want to plot the data like in this below image.
[image]
How to achieve this with stacked area chart in Pandas python. ( my x-axis should have both my label and year values and based on that grouping of y-axis should plot values )

The code I tried with seaborn as well normal

```
dF.plot(figsize=(20,8), x =['Label','Year'], y ='Total', kind = 'area', stacked = True)

ax = df.plot(x="label", y="Total", legend=False, figsize=(10,8))
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.plot(x="label", y="Dst_Port", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r", figsize=(10,8))
ax.figure.legend()
plt.show()
```

My current graph can plot with single x-axis column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502106/2847330) for plotting the category grid lines:

- Group by data with "Label", "Year" and sum the "Total".
- Plot as follows

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["FTP","02/2018",1000],["BBBB","02/2018",1500],["SSSS","02/2018",1400],["Dddd","02/2018",3000],["FTP","02/2017",1800],["BBBB","02/2017",1700],["SSSS","02/2017",1600],["Dddd","02/2017",1500]], columns=["Label","Year","Total"])

df = df.groupby(["Label", "Year"]) \
       .agg(Total=("Total","sum")) 

def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(labels)]

def label_group_bar_table(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1

ax = df.plot.area(figsize=(20,5))
ax.set_xticklabels("")
ax.set_xlabel("")
label_group_bar_table(ax, df)
```

[image]

Comment: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <generator object label_len.<locals>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fc0b11a5740> of type <class 'generator'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function. getting this error in line no of return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(labels)]. or getting error with itertools not defined

Comment: Please share a sample dataframe creation code for your use case.

Comment: I have taken the data from the table using spark.sql('select Label,Total,Year from sqlview') and converted 
pandasDF=sqlDFF.toPandas()
df = pandasDF.groupby(["Label", "Year"]) \
       .agg(Total=("Total","sum"))
I am new to python, bare me if my questions are bad

Comment: DataFrame[Label: string, Year: string, Total: bigint] this is my spark datafram after retrieve from sql and after converted to pandas
                       Label     Year    Total
0                     AAA 02/2018   193360
1                     BBB 01/1970       14
2                     BBB 02/2018  4567511

Comment: Are you plotting on pyspark df? You should plot on pandas df.

Comment: yes i am plotting using pandas ly. after retrieving data I will convert spark dataframe to pandas

Comment: Your error is for spark dataframe. What is output of `pandasDF.dtypes`?

Comment: Label    object
Year     object
Total     int64
dtype: object

Comment: Check your imports and restart python kernel. Looks like you have a different `sum` function imported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250347/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-azhar-khan).