# Create a bar chart in python grouping the x axis by 2 variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to create a bar chart using python, where I can group the X axis by 2 variables. The data I need to graph is the following

| Country | City | Number of Universities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Berlin | 30 |
| Germany | Munich | 20 |
| Germany | Hamburg | 10 |
| France | Paris | 40 |
| France | Marseille | 5 |
| France | Lyon | 10 |
| France | Nice | 5 |
| Spain | Madrid | 25 |
| Spain | Barcelona | 15 |
| Spain | Valencia | 10 |
| Spain | Seville | 7 |
| Denmark | Copenhagen | 10 |
| Denmark | Aarhus | 5 |
| Italy | Rome | 20 |
| Italy | Milan | 15 |
| Italy | Naples | 8 |
| Italy | Florence | 7 |
| Austria | Vienna | 12 |
| Austria | Salzburg | 4 |

I share the code to create it below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dictionary with the data
data = {
    'Country': ['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France',
                'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Denmark', 'Denmark', 'Italy',
                'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Austria', 'Austria'],
    'City': ['Berlin', 'Munich', 'Hamburg', 'Paris', 'Marseille', 'Lyon', 'Nice',
             'Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Seville', 'Copenhagen', 'Aarhus',
             'Rome', 'Milan', 'Naples', 'Florence', 'Vienna', 'Salzburg']
}

# Convert the dictionary into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Count the number of universities per city and add it as a new column
universities_count = [30, 20, 10, 40, 5, 10, 5, 25, 15, 10, 7, 10, 5, 20, 15, 8, 7, 12, 4]
df['Number of Universities'] = universities_count

# Show the DataFrame
print(df)
```

The objective is to generate the following graph:
[image]

in advance, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19184484/7750891

Comment: See also this example, which was recently added to the Matplotlib documentation https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/ticks/multilevel_ticks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how closely you want to replicate this, you'll need an approach that can calculate the necessary height/placement of your group labels and tick lines.

I wrote a helper function to do this that calculates the current height (in points) of the xaxis of an inputted `Axes`.

After that, we effectively need 3 sets of `Axes.xaxis` to work with:

1. For the individual `'City'` level ticks
2. For the grouped `'Country'` level ticks
3. For the lines that span from the `Axes` down to the bottom of the `'Country'` level labels.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': [
        'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'France', 'France', 'France', 'France',
        'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Denmark', 'Denmark', 'Italy',
        'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Austria', 'Austria'
    ],
    'City': [
        'Berlin', 'Munich', 'Hamburg', 'Paris', 'Marseille', 'Lyon', 'Nice',
         'Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Seville', 'Copenhagen', 'Aarhus',
         'Rome', 'Milan', 'Naples', 'Florence', 'Vienna', 'Salzburg'
    ],
    'Number of Universities': [
        30, 20, 10, 40, 5, 10, 5, 25, 15, 10, 7, 10, 5, 20, 15, 8, 7, 12, 4
    ]
})

plot_df = df.sort_values(['Country', 'City'])

###

def get_xaxis_height(ax):
    height = 0
    axes = [ax] + ax.child_axes
    for ax in axes:
        height += ax.xaxis.get_tightbbox().height
        height += ax.xaxis.get_tick_params()['pad']
    return height * 72 / fig.dpi

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rc('font', size=12)

## Create base chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ax.spines[['left', 'top', 'right']].set_visible(False) # turn off all spines

bc = ax.bar('City', 'Number of Universities', data=plot_df, width=.6)
ax.bar_label(bc)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(
    rotation=90,
    bottom=False,
    length=0,
    pad=1,   # adjust pad to move individual labels further/closer to bottom spine
)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(left=False)

## Add group labels underneath existing rotated labels
label_locs = (
    plot_df.assign(tick_loc=np.arange(len(plot_df)))
    .groupby('Country')['tick_loc']
    .mean()
)
ax_bottom = get_xaxis_height(ax)
group_label_ax = ax.secondary_xaxis(location='bottom')
group_label_ax.set_xticks(label_locs, labels=label_locs.index, ha='center')
group_label_ax.tick_params(
    bottom=False,
    pad=10,  # adjust pad to move your group labels further/closer to the individual labels
    length=ax_bottom
)

## add long tick lines where needed
line_locs = (
    plot_df.assign(tick_loc=np.arange(len(plot_df)))
    .loc[lambda d:
        d['Country'] != d['Country'].shift(), 'tick_loc'
    ]
    - 0.5
).tolist()
line_locs += [len(df) - .5]

ax_bottom = get_xaxis_height(ax)
tickline_ax = ax.secondary_xaxis(location='bottom')
tickline_ax.set_xticks(line_locs)
tickline_ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, length=ax_bottom, pad=0)
ax.set_xlim(-.5, len(ax.containers[0]) - .5)

## adjust spine & tick colors
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('gainsboro')
tickline_ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(
    color='gainsboro', 
    labelcolor='black', 
    width=ax.spines['bottom'].get_linewidth() * 2
)

## adjust y-ticks to be multiples of 5
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax.margins(y=.2)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! The solution provided fits perfectly with what I needed.